# Exception in thread "main": java.lang.StackOverflowError,Why?

Tags: java

This is my code; resulting in that StackOverflow error:

```
public class NucleousInterviewQuestion {

NucleousInterviewQuestion interviewQuestion = new  NucleousInterviewQuestion();

public NucleousInterviewQuestion() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NucleousInterviewQuestion interviewQuestion= new NucleousInterviewQuestion();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

This here:

```
public class NucleousInterviewQuestion {
  NucleousInterviewQuestion interviewQuestion = new  NucleousInterviewQuestion();
```

creates an endless recursion.

The point is: you call `new` in your main method. When you do that, you run the "init" code that belongs to this class. "init" code consists of:

- field init statements
- and a constructor call

And you got one field which has init code ... that calls `new` again; for the very same class.

The "solution" in that sense: understand how classes are initialized. Of course classes can have fields that reference other objects; even objects of the same class; but then you need (for example) something like:

```
public class Example {
  Example other;

  public Example() {
    other = null;
  }

  public Example(Example other) {
    this.other = other;
  }
```

This way you can reference to another object from the same class; without creating a recursion.

Answer (score 2):

The field interviewQuestion is creating another NucleousInterviewQuestion object, and this new object is creating another one and so on - recursion...